# How do I import data from SQL via Prisma into React without running into a Promise error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, typescript, prisma

I'm currently trying to bring data from my MS SQL database into React components without causing a Promise error. Basically, this inherently involves async functions, but every time I use them, I get an error claiming that I'm trying to pass a Promise rather than an actual array into React.

How do I overcome this issue and pull data via prisma into Typescript and then transfer it into a React component without having complaints about a Promise?

Here's my code:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8081/api/fRED_Market_Yield_10Y");
  const my10y = await res.json();
  return {
    props: { my10y },
  };
};

export function MY10Y({ my10y: [] }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {my10y?.map((p: { DateTime: Key | null | undefined; Value: boolean | ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | null | undefined; }) => {
        return (
          <div key={p.DateTime}>
            <p>
              {p.Value}%
            </p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

// pages/api/products.js
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
import { Key, ReactChild, ReactFragment, ReactPortal } from "react";

let prisma: PrismaClient<Prisma.PrismaClientOptions, never, Prisma.RejectOnNotFound | Prisma.RejectPerOperation | undefined>;

prisma = new PrismaClient();

//export default prisma;

export default async function handle(req: any, res: { json: (arg0: any) => void; }) {
  const my10y = await prisma.fRED_Market_Yield_10Y.findMany();
  res.json(my10y);
}
```

Comment: You kinda need to show us some code in order for us to understand what you are doing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added my code! Thanks for pointing that out! @Community